# Minimal Spanning Tree vs Minimum Spanning Tree

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

I got confused about minimal and minimum in context of graph theory.
Although, I have understanding that minimal means more than one minimum i.e. none qualifies as actual minimum so we say them minimal.

What exactly does minimal spanning tree mean? Also, what exactly does 'minimal edge' mean?

How do they differ from minimum spanning tree?
How are 'minimal edge' different from minimum edge?

This doubt arose due to the statement:

S: There exists a minimum weight edge in G, which exists in every minimum spanning tree of G.

Can we say on using word 'minimum' it's implied that there is only one minimum weight edge. Besides, statement used "exists" which is singular.

Comment: Where did you encounter "minimal spanning tree" and "minimal edge"? This statement doesn't mention them. Minimum here means a global minimum: a tree/edge with the smallest weight (there is no other tree/edge with a smaller weight).

Comment: Today, here: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045727/there-exists-a-does-it-mean-at-least-one-or-exactly-one#comment8355603_4045727). Although, someone else pointed out too, but he seem to have deleted his comment.

Comment: @Dmitry, Sir, Does all edges with minimum weight qualifies as Global Minimum, or Do we say Global minimum in that case don't exist?

Comment: I agree with this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2142655/743044 . Note that "minimum" implies "minimal". So it's not incorrect to use "minimal" instead of "minimum", but no reason to do that.

Comment: All such edges are global minima. (I use word "global" only to stress that they are minima across the set of *all* edges)

Comment: @Dmitry Sir, I went through the question whose one of answer you provided in above link. But, the 1st answer here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2142656/894382) essentially says: "Something is the minimum if it is the unique minimal element". I'm unable to understand whether it is semantically same as "Minimum" is "Smallest".

Comment: "a minimum weight edge" is an edge that has minimum weight. You consider a set of all edge weights, and there must exist a (unique) minimum among these weights. Any edge with such weight is a minimum weight edge. There is a difference between minimal and minimum (as described), but I think you focus on the wrong thing. It's usually clear when one should use these words: "minimum" means the best and "minimal" means that you can't improve it. E.g. a maximum matching is the best matching (with the maximum number of edges), and a maximal matching is the one where you can't add another edge.

Comment: @Dmitry, Sir, Thanks for clarifications. I now get where to use minimal and minimum. But, then technically, statement goes wrong when more than one edge have same weight, as it's not unique, we shouldn't call it minimum.

Comment: When people say "minimal spanning tree", they probably mean "minimum spanning tree".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, Sir, About "minimal edge" as well?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Answer (score 1):

A *minimum weight edge* is an edge whose weight is minimal among all edges. There can be more than one minimum weight edge. All minimum weight edges have the same weight.

Similarly, a *minimum spanning tree* is a spanning tree whose weight is minimal among all spanning trees. There can be more than one minimum spanning tree. All minimum spanning trees have the same weight.

In some cases, there is a distinction between *minimum* and *minimal*. For example, a *minimum vertex cover* is a vertex cover whose weight is minimal among all vertex covers. In contrast, a *minimal vertex cover* is a vertex cover, any proper subset of which isn't a vertex cover. Finding a minimal vertex cover is easy – start with the set of all vertices, and repeatedly remove a vertex as long as it is possible to do so while maintaining the property of covering all edges. In contrast, finding a minimum vertex cover is expected to be hard (the corresponding decision problem is NP-hard).

The same property of being minimal doesn't make much sense for edges and spanning trees. When people say *minimal edge* or *minimal spanning tree*, they probably mean *minimum (weight) edge* and *minimum spanning tree*.

Comment: Sir, I have a confusion, saying something is "minimum" only if it's unique minimal, Is that incorrect?[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2142656/894382) If graph have all edge weights same, it's bit inconvenient to say graph have all minimum weight edges.

Comment: You can use a word in any way you like, as long as everybody understands what you mean by the word. The standard definition of *minimum* doesn't imply uniqueness.

Comment: For example, the minimum value attained by the sine function is $-1$. It is not attained uniquely.